# how to make a half circle tunnel through a cement slab?

Tags: concrete, cement

There is a slab of concrete in my backyard, and I need to make a half circle cut out in it like this picture below. This is for a 3" pipe to sit in.

How would I go about doing this?

[image: picture]

Comment: With a masonry blade attached to a grinder. Hold grinder at a medium angle to the concrete and make gradual shallow passes.

Comment: To provide more details for this answer - a diamond blade and a 4 inch angle grinder. It can be used dry. Be sure to wear a mask and goggles. It will make lots of dust.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than try to shape the slab so it conforms to the pipe, cut the slab slightly wider and deeper than the pipe. Mix a loose batch of cement, pour into slab cut, and embed pipe into concrete.